# Shiny server not working after update to 1.5

Tags: r, shiny

I had a shiny app working using shiny-server 1.4.2.786 and after upgrading to 1.5.9.923 and I get the following error:

```
Error in if (nchar(bookmarkStateDir) > 0) { : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
Calls: local -> eval.parent -> eval -> eval -> eval -> eval
Execution halted
```

If I roll back to 1.4.2.786, everything works as expected, therefore I don't think it's an issue with permissions or general shiny config files. Any idea what this is due to? I couldn't find any solutions online, however, I did read that 1.5 introduces big changes in Node.js, so perhaps this causes errors? Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like this should be a [bug report](https://github.com/rstudio/shiny-server/issues). (Sorry, that's all I got.)

Comment: What does `nchar(bookmarkStateDir)` return?

Comment: @r2evans yes I think I will report it. And nchar(bookmarkStateDir) is an error that pops out of the shiny-server so would take a lot of digging around to find out - I was hoping it would be a lot simpler. I think it comes from [the shiny-server SockJSAdapter](https://github.com/rstudio/shiny-server/blob/master/R/SockJSAdapter.R) potentially?